# Bootstrap breakpoints not working in React Bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm working with react Bootstrap. I have designed a layout which I want to refactor on small screens. All I want to do is, at certain breakpoints I want my h3 elements and image resized. I've been using the following:

**Code from index.css** :

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { 
    .thumbnailImg{
    width: 30%;
    }

    h3{
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
 }

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { 
    .thumbnailImg{
    width: 35%;
    }

    h3{
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

     }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .thumbnailImg{
    width: 40%;
    }

    h3{
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }

}
```

Now for some reasons none of the breakpoints have been working. h3 remains 1.75 rem throughout the whole time. Not only just the h3 element but the image is also not resizing as defined. Can anyone could tell me what is that I'm doing wrong here.

**Here is my component that has been using this style**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './index.css';

export const MyIcons = ({source,name}) => (
        <div className="col-sm-4 addMargin50 text-center">
            <Image className="thumbnailImg" src={ process.env.PUBLIC_URL + source } alt={name} roundedCircle />
            <h3 className="font-nunito text-uppercase"> {name} </h3>
        </div>
    )
```

I also tried making a separate class to define the font-sizes on different breakpoints and added that class to my image and h3 element however none of them is working either.

Comment: can you show a picture with inspector on these screens sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems not with react, it's the order of your media queries. If you have overlapping rules it will always pick the final rule that was delcared. If you reverse the order of your media queries you should get what you want.

I have edited this answer to be more clear.

You should order your media queries from largest device to smallest device.

```
/* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .thumbnailImg{
    width: 40%;
    }

    h3{
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }

}

/* Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)*/
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { 
    .thumbnailImg{
    width: 35%;
    }

    h3{
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

     }



/* Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px) */
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { 
    .thumbnailImg{
    width: 30%;
    }

    h3{
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/txL5chk0/2/

Also, I am sure I don't need to tell you that the comments you have in your css file are not valid comments in CSS and should not be included with your code....

Comment: Tried that with no success. Can you please elaborate what do you mean by reversing the order?

Comment: So you're likely including your comments in the css file (which I mentioned in the answer). If you look at the JS fiddle, the image/h3 element resizes. Can you provide a link that actually recreats this problem?

Comment: Yes that was because of the incorrect comments I've been using ( though I copied the code from bootstrap's official website ). Anyways thanks a lot for helping!